# Computing a Lag on a Table in R

Tags: r

I have a data table, my_data, with 3 variables, symbol, date, stock price and 141851 observations.
The idea is to compute a Lag of 1 day on the stock price, taking care to group by symbol first, otherwise I will have lags computed using values from the previous stock in the data frame.

This are some rows from the table.

| Symbol | date | stock price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MSFT | 2019-02-12 | 106.8100 |
| MSFT | 2019-02-13 | 106.9000 |
| MSFT | 2019-02-14 | 108.2200 |
| APPL | 2018-01-02 | 168.9873 |
| APPL | 2018-01-03 | 168.9579 |
| APPL | 2018-01-04 | 169.7427 |

I need to to calculate the ratio **{price(i)-price(i-1)} / price(i-1)** for the whole table.
But I cannot shift my it.

I started with R today, so I'm just struggling a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using a built-in dataset. I recommend `dplyr` for these calculations. See the [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf).

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data(ChickWeight)

df <- as_tibble(ChickWeight)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Chick) %>% 
  mutate(change = (weight-first(weight))/first(weight)*100) %>% 
  mutate(change = round(change,2))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, change := round(weight - first(weight))/first(weight) * 100, 2), Chick]
```

#### data

```
data(ChickWeight)
df1 <- ChickWeight
```